# Buscar dados simples SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

Quero retornar apenas dois dados simples em `TextView` usando `SQLite`.
Tenho uma tabela "Produtos" comum e outra tabela temporária "Informações" que uso `SUM()` para somar a coluna da primeira tabela.

**DBHelper**:

```
    public List<ProdutoDAO> getTotais() {
            List<ProdutoDAO> list = new ArrayList<ProdutoDAO>();
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + QUANTIDADE + ") AS " + TOTAL_QUANTIDADE + ", SUM(" + TOTAL + ") AS " + TOTAL_VALOR + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                ProdutoDAO produto = new ProdutoDAO();
                produto.setTotalValor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_VALOR)));
                produto.setTotalQuantidade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_QUANTIDADE)));
                list.add(produto);
                cursor.moveToLast();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Que erro está ocorrendo? Por favor, explique ou coloque o printStackTrace.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi muito bem, e sem o erro que ocorre fica meio difícil!

Mas tenho algumas considerações:

1. A função SUM, retorna a soma do valores, então irá retornar apenas uma linha!

Não há necessidade do método retornar uma lista! 
Acredito que apenas o objeto supre sua necessidade!

2. Partindo do princípio que existe apenas um resultado, então verificamos apenas se o cursor vai para a primeira posição:

   **if (cursor.moveToFirst())**

Em caso positivo, vamos popular os dados.

Segue uma sugestão:

```
public  ProdutoDAO getTotais() {

            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + QUANTIDADE + ") AS " + TOTAL_QUANTIDADE + ", SUM(" + TOTAL + ") AS " + TOTAL_VALOR + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                ProdutoDAO produto = new ProdutoDAO();
                produto.setTotalValor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_VALOR)));
                produto.setTotalQuantidade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_QUANTIDADE)));
                 return produto;


            }else{

               return null;

             }

 }
```

Comment: Obrigado Thiago!

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.
Modifiquei completamente meu código e resolvi o problema desta forma:

DBHelper:

```
public Produto getInfo() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + TOTAL + ") AS " + TOTAL_VALOR + ", SUM(" + QUANTIDADE + ") AS " + TOTAL_QUANTIDADE + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
    Produto produto = new Produto();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            produto.setTotalValor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_VALOR)));
            produto.setTotalQuantidade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_QUANTIDADE)));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    onCreate(db);
    return produto;
}
```

Obrigado pessoal!